# Getting into a scrolling loop when shifting DomElements on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svelte, dom-manipulation

I'm building a virtual grid of sorts, that will place content into the viewport as it's required, particularly on user scrolling.

I've been able to achieve this kind of behavior with React, but I seem to be having trouble with svelte.

```
    <script>
    let scroll;
    $: height = Math.floor(scroll/200)*200;
</script>

<svelte:window bind:scrollY={scroll} />


<div class="holder" style="height:{height}px"></div>
<div class="box"></div>



<style>
    :global(body) {
        height: 20000px;
    }
    .box {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: aqua;
    }
    .holder {

    }
</style>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e381d1eb9a584b40b2083dded118c460?version=3.42.2)

As I scroll, and the bottom div is increased in height to raise the blue box, something triggers a further scroll, which then triggers a further height increase which triggers a further scroll.

So basically as you scroll a little the scroll bar goes crazy and slides down on pc.

Ideally the page should scroll normally from user inpu.

Not sure if this is a problem with svelte, or if this is some default browser behavior.

Edit: change code and repl to reflect my requirement a bit more, which shows why setting "position: fixed" css wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code setting the height of the .holder changes the scroll. So it falls in continuous loop till meets bottom.

```
<script>
    let scroll;
    $: top = Math.floor(scroll/200)*200;
</script>

<svelte:window bind:scrollY={scroll} />

<div class="box" style="top:{top}px"></div>

<style>
    :global(body) {
        height: 20000px;
    }
    .box {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: aqua;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I guess this is the right answer. But is this behavior documented/described anywhere? Any way to stop it? If my project does require the height to be changed like that?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.holder` and instead use `position: fixed` and `top: 8px`.

```
<script>
    let scroll;
</script>

<svelte:window bind:scrollY={scroll} />

<div class="box" style="position:fixed;top:8px"></div>

<style>
    :global(body) {
        height: 20000px;
    }
    .box {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: aqua;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, you're absolutely right, this will solve the problem with the blue box. However that's just the simplest example to reproduce the problem. As I add the needed complexity the elements are changed in a different way, Dom items get added, moved and removed in different static positions on the page, so setting them to just be fixed isn't going to be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to increase the height, you can do it like follow code.

```
<script>
    let scroll;
    $: height = Math.floor((scroll - 1)/200)*200;
</script>

<svelte:window bind:scrollY={scroll} />


<div class="holder" style="height:{height}px"></div>
<div class="box"></div>



<style>
    :global(body) {
        height: 20000px;
    }
    .box {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: aqua;
    }
    .holder {

    }
</style>
```